# WinForm Calculate all gridview to date

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I want calculate date values like the image.

[image]

And there is any simple way to add footer in MetroGridView that calculate like label value?
I'm currently using label to show total values.
Any suggests or ideas?

-Thanks

Here is the code:

```
private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // check start date
        if (dtStart.Value > dtEnd.Value)
        {
            MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Start Date wrong!", "Error");
            return;
        }

        DateTime Now = dtEnd.Value;
        int Years = new DateTime(Now.Subtract(dtStart.Value).Ticks).Year - 1;
        DateTime PastYearDate = dtStart.Value.AddYears(Years);
        int Months = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            if (PastYearDate.AddMonths(i) == Now)
            {
                Months = i;
                break;
            }
            else if (PastYearDate.AddMonths(i) >= Now)
            {
                Months = i - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        int Days = Now.Subtract(PastYearDate.AddMonths(Months)).Days;

        int index = metroGrid1.Rows.Add();
        metroGrid1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = Years;
        metroGrid1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = Months;
        metroGrid1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = Days;

        for (int i = 0; i < metroGrid1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            Years += Convert.ToInt32(metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            Months += Convert.ToInt32(metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            Days += Convert.ToInt32(metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value); 

            // stuck here ...

            lbltotal.Text = "Total: " + Years.ToString() + " years, " + Months.ToString() + " months and " + Days.ToString() + " days";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested Kuo-hsuan Hsu solution and it returns:
Total: 19 years, 8 months and 3 days

I tried a little bit similar (see below) and get:
Total: 19 years, 7 months and 26 days 
Windows calculator tells me: 19 Years, 7 Month, 3 weeks, 5 days what is the same as above. But anyway, over a long period my code is not exact and Kuo-hsuan Hsu code isen't it as well.

```
       // taken values from grid
        int years = 18 ;
        int months = 18 ;
        int days = 57 ;
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today; // 2018-11-17
        DateTime futuredate = today.AddYears(years);
        futuredate = futuredate.AddMonths(months);
        futuredate = futuredate.AddDays(days); // 2038-07-13

        TimeSpan tsp = futuredate - today;
        years = tsp.Days / 365;
        futuredate = futuredate.AddYears(-years);
        tsp = futuredate - today;
        months = tsp.Days / 30;
        futuredate = futuredate.AddMonths(-months);
        tsp = futuredate - today;
        days = tsp.Days;
        string res1 = "Total: " + years.ToString() + " years, " + months.ToString() + " months and " + days.ToString() + " days";
```

I am not happy with the code above.
I am thinking to run in an loop from start date to end date and calculate the values.
That would enable me even to count only working days - maybe having a list of public holidays for the next 100 years.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This one is calculate for past not future :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you should put this statement :

`lbltotal.Text = "Total: " + Years.ToString() + " years, " + Months.ToString() + " months and " + Days.ToString() + " days";`

outside for loop.

And in for loop, you use three Int: "Years", "Months", "Days", to represent the accumulation of the time span, but actually they are Int, not Timespan, so after the loop, it could be like: 5 years 20 months 78 days, I assume that is not the kind of result you want.

Why don't you use TimeSpan type to replace those three Int ?

Edit:
You could use the code below:

```
// never mind the date of s1 (1990,1,1),it's not important, just as a start point for the Timespan ts1 to do accumulate;
DateTime s1 = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1);
TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan();


for (int i = 0; i < metroGrid1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    ts1 += s1.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value)).AddMonths(Convert.ToInt32(metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value)).AddYears(Convert.ToInt32(metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value)) - s1;
} 


int daysResult;
int monthsResult;
int yearsResult;


// get the total number of days, then /365 to get the year count;
yearsResult = ts1.Days /365;

// get the month count by /30 from the remainder of /365;
monthsResult = (ts1.Days % 365) / 30;

// get the day count from the remainder of /30;
daysResult = (ts1.Days % 365) % 30;

lbltotal.Text = "Total: " + yearsResult.ToString() + " years, " + monthsResult.ToString() + " months and " + daysResult.ToString() + " days";
```

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. It works but it calculates bit different. When I enter start date: 2017.05.01, end date: 2018.10.31 it would be: 1 year, 5 months and 30 days but in label: 1 year 6 months and 3 days. I will try resolve this problem using your code. Thanks for your hard work :)